# How to vertically align a math fraction inside table cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, fractions

Consider the following minimal working example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{4cm}}
\toprule
variables & definition \tabularnewline
\midrule
Tobin's $q$ & \(\displaystyle \frac{\text{MVCS} + \text{MVPS} + \text{DEBT}}{\text{book\ value\ of\ assets}}\)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

whose output is as follows

[image]

Now, I would rather have the **cell contents aligned on top**, as in

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I think your cell contents are already aligned top.

Comment: Perhaps just the uncommon math display style that you are using is what makes it seems not aligned top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following custom command can be used to remove the tabular management of the line spacing

```
\newcommand{\notopspacing}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}{#1}}
```

Applying this command to your code (as it is)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\notopspacing}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{4cm}}
    \toprule
    variables & definition \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \notopspacing{Tobin's $q$} & \notopspacing{\(\displaystyle \frac{\text{MVCS} + \text{MVPS} + \text{DEBT}}{\text{book\ value\ of\ assets}}\)} \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Gives the following output

[image]

**Note** that there are lots of improvements you should carry out in your code! (other answers only show some)

Answer (score 4):

Math mode and `\frac` put the baseline at (slightly below) the center.  This solution uses a second tabular to achieve the desired effect.

Note, unless you want to specify the widths, you don't need `p` columns for the outer tabular in this case.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{4cm}}
\toprule
variables & definition \tabularnewline
\midrule
Tobin's $q$ & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  MVCS + MVPS + DEBT \\
  \hline
  book value of assets
\end{tabular}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```