# How can I insert a itemize in a table-cell and keep the shape of the table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, itemize, cell

I have created a table, and I have fixed its width, but the problem is that when I tried to add `\itemize` in cell, the distance between the first word of the item and the above line is different from the distance which is between another first line of a cell and the above line. As shown in picture the picture:

Picture 1 : before add itemize.

Picture 2 : after itemizing.

[image]
[image]

The latex code of table :

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Draft Paper.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{cuted}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{array}


%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%


\begin{document}
    \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
    \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
    \usepackage{array}
    
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{table*}[htp]
    %\scriptsize        
    \centering
    %\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    
    
    \begin{tabular} {|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 
    \hline
    
    Text text text
    &
    Text 
    &
    Text text text
    & 
    Text text text& 
    text & text & text & test& text
    
    \\ \hline
    
    {\multirow [c]{10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ {Feedforward} }}}  & 
    %[origin=c]
    {\multirow [c]{15}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ Regression }}}
    
    
     & 
    
    Text text text& 
    Text text text& 
    
    %\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
    item item item
    
    
     & 
     
     
    
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
     -item 
     -item
    
    \end{tabular}  
    
    &   
    Text text text
    & Text text text
    & r1 \\ \cline{3-9}&  & 
    
    Text text text& 
    Text text text& 
     
     
     
     %\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    -Item1 -item 2 -item3
    %\end{tabular}
    
    & 
    
    Text text text&Text text text
    & Text text text
    & 
    
    r2 \\ 
    
    
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-9} 
    
    \multirow{2}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text text }}  &  
    &
    Text text text&
    Text text text& 
    
    
    Text text text& 
    
    Text text text& 
    Text text text& 
    %\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
    //
    %} 
    & 
    
    r3 
    
    \\ 
    \hline
    
    %\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 3}}
    
    \multirow{2}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Feedforward   }} & 
    
    \multirow{2}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Classification }}
    & 
    Text text text&
    Text text text& 
    %\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
     
    Item. 
    Item. 
    item. 
    Item. 
    %\end{tabular}
    &
    Text text text& 
    Text text text & 
    Text text text
    
    & 
    
    
    Text
    
    \\ \hline
    
    \end{tabular}
    
    \end{table*}
    \end{center}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: been following your posts -- i think you are copying a code from somewhere and its totally wierd code-- better to upload a photo of what is your desired output or a hand drawn sketch--easier for everyone to help--this way you will keep struggling for every cell code-- apologies but only trying to help is all

Comment: @jsbibra No it is my code, and I took a screen !

Comment: @jsbibra I have replaced my original text with the words " Text" because I won't share original text.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example that can be compiled and reproduce your problematic output, starting by \documentclass{article} (or whatever class you are using) and ending with \end{document}

Comment: If you would like to adjust (or rather remove) the table line spacing managment by the `tabular` package, you can check out this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549267/91556

Comment: Your code is not compilable. You can't use `\usepackage` after `\begin{document}`. Please also don't load packages more than once.

Comment: Please clarify: What does "Picture 1 : before add itemize.

Picture 2 : after itemizing."  mean? There is no occurence of `itemize` in the code you included.

Comment: Did you try to replace `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} -Item1 -item 2 -item3 \end{tabular}` with `\begin{itemize} \item item  \item item  \item item \end{itemize}` and got the second image in your question?

Comment: Probably you want to add `\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textendash,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}
` to the preamble and use `\begin{tabitemize} \item item  \item item  \item item \end{tabitemize}` in the table?